# Stored procedures in SQL Server Errors Unsolved

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
  CREATE FUNCTION CHI_X2 
  (
  @a1 INT,
  @b1 INT,
  @a2 INT,
  @b2 INT
  )
  RETURNS int
  AS
  BEGIN
  -- Declare the return variable here
  DECLARE @Result int

  DECLARE @tr1 INT;
  DECLARE @tr2 INT;
  DECLARE @tc1 INT;
  DECLARE @tc2 INT;
  DECLARE @ca1 INT;
  DECLARE @ca2 INT;
  DECLARE @cb1 INT;
  DECLARE @cb2 INT;
  DECLARE @xi INT;
  DECLARE @nt INT;

  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pro1]
  AS
  BEGIN

     SET @tr1 = @a1+@b1
     SET @tr2 = @a2+@b2
     SET @tc1 = @a1+@a2
     SET @tc2 = @b1+@b2
     SET @nt = @tr1+@tr2
     SET @ca1 =(@tc1/@nt*@tr1)
     SET @ca2 =(@tc1/@nt*@tr2)
     SET @cb1 =(@tc2/@nt*@tr1)
     SET @cb2 =(@tc2/@nt*@tr2)
     SET @xi =((power((@a1 -@ca1),2)/@ca1)+(power((@a2 -@ca2),2)/@ca2)+(power((@b1-@cb1),2)/@cb1)+(power((@b2 -@cb2),2)/@cb2))
     -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here


  SELECT @Result = @xi

  -- Return the result of the function
  RETURN @Result


  --END CHI_X2

  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pro2]
  AS
  begin

     DECLARE @max_chi INT
     DECLARE @maxpos INT
     DECLARE @n INT
     DECLARE @SWV_CUR_OUT_Sessionnumber VARCHAR(255)
     DECLARE @SWV_CUR_OUT_sessioncount VARCHAR(255)
     DECLARE @SWV_CUR_OUT_timespent VARCHAR(255)
     DECLARE @SWV_cursor_var1 CURSOR
     DECLARE @SWV_CUR_IN_Sessionnumber VARCHAR(255)
     DECLARE @SWV_CUR_IN_sessioncount VARCHAR(255)
     DECLARE @SWV_CUR_IN_timespent VARCHAR(255)
     delete from CH_TABLE
     commit
     SET @SWV_cursor_var1 = CURSOR  FOR select sessionnumber, sessioncount, timespent from clusters  order by sessionnumber asc
     OPEN @SWV_cursor_var1
     FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var1 INTO @SWV_CUR_OUT_sessionnumber,@SWV_CUR_OUT_sessioncount,@SWV_CUR_OUT_timespent
     while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     begin
        SET @max_chi = -999
        SET @maxpos = NULL
        SET @SWV_cursor_var1 = CURSOR  FOR select sessionnumber, sessioncount, timespent from clusters  order by sessionnumber asc
        OPEN @SWV_cursor_var1
        FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var1 INTO @SWV_CUR_IN_sessionnumber,@SWV_CUR_IN_sessioncount,@SWV_CUR_IN_timespent
        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
           select   @n = count(*) from(select x1 as x from CH_TABLE union all select x2 from CH_TABLE) AS TabAl
           where x = @SWV_CUR_OUT_sessionnumber or x = @SWV_CUR_IN_sessionnumber
   if @n = 0
  begin
    -- SET @xi = round(CHI_X2(cur_out.sessioncount,cur_out.timespent,cur_in.sessioncount,cur_in.timespent),2)
     if @xi > @max_chi
     begin
        SET @max_chi = @xi
        SET @maxpos = cur_in.sessionnumber
     end
  end

     FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var1 INTO @SWV_CUR_IN_sessionnumber,@SWV_CUR_IN_sessioncount,@SWV_CUR_IN_timespent
        end
  if @max_chi > -999
  begin
  INSERT INTO CH_TABLE(SNO, P, T) VALUES(cur_out.sessionnumber, @maxpos, @max_chi)

     commit
  end


  CLOSE @SWV_cursor_var1
  FETCH NEXT FROM @SWV_cursor_var1 INTO @SWV_CUR_OUT_sessionnumber,@SWV_CUR_OUT_sessioncount,@SWV_CUR_OUT_timespent
     end
     CLOSE @SWV_cursor_var1

  END
```

I come from a MySQL background, and have recently began migrating to SQL Server.

I can't, for the life of me, find an example of a stored procedure that does the following in SQL Server:
- Multi-lined
- Contains both input and output parameters
- Sets one of the output parameters within the stored procedure

Can anyone provide some insight? I.e. Why does the following not work?

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CHI_X2, Line 31
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Nsg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CHI_X2, Line 56
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CHI_X2, Line 112
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So I Google "*Sql Server Stored Procedure Output Parameters*", and the first link has a multi-line example with both input and output procedures.

Comment: And your example isn't working because 1) You can nest object *calls*, but never object *definitions*, 2) you never end the first Function definition, 3) you never declare any output parameters and 4) variables and parameters are always local, never global.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, [here's a basic introduction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to ouptput parameters.

Here's the short and sweet of it.  Note the `OUTPUT` keyword on the output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspMyProc
@SomeParameter varchar(10),
@TheOutputParameter varchar OUTPUT
AS
  -- Do stuff
  SELECT @TheOutputParameter = somecolumn FROM something
  -- or
  SET @TheOutputParameter = someresult
RETURN
```